# How to fetch data using NSUrl session in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to fetch JSON data and parse it using NSUrl session but getting null every time - Also in addition to that i want o show all data in table view

```
NSError *error;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2iodh4vg0eortkl/facts.json"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


    NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Value", @"Key",   nil];

    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


        NSLog(@"Resopnse == %@",response);

        if (response != nil) {
            NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            NSLog(@"JSon dict === %@",jsonDict);
        }

    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
```

May I know what i am doing wrong is anything other good way to do same?

Comment: What is null? `response ` ? `data` ? `jsonDict`? Usually, you don't put params for GET into HTTPBody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2iodh4vg0eortkl/facts.json"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSData * responseData = [requestReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
    }] resume];
```

Comment: Do you have any example of how should i create table view programmaticaly and display data from JSON response in tableview with images in asynchronsly

Comment: You should google it for that...:) but here is helpful link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for the same. Hope it will solve your problem.

```
    NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:yourUrl];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary *dicResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
             NSLog(@"%@",dicResponse);
         }
     }];
```

Comment: Question is asked for `NSURLSession`, Not for `NSURLConnection`